# Is there a way to read arbitrary JSON from Kafka message and forward that arbitrary JSON as identical content Kafka message?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, quarkus

My intention is to use Java (more specifically Quarkus native) to read arbitrary Kafka message content as JSON from a configurable stream, persist it, then eventually write a new message to another configurable stream using the content from the initial message.
All without de-serializing the JSON content, thus making it opaque to the application what was being passed.

Of course it could be some other format like Avro, but as long as I can make the code work with any content from any stream it still solves the problem.

The intention is to avoid building POJOs to hold the data because the data could be any.

Is there a way to read arbitrary JSON from Kafka message and forward that arbitrary JSON as identical content Kafka message?

Comment: Seems like you want to use  ByteArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve you can use any on the following strategy.

Read the message as a string (using a `String` payload type on the signature or a `Message<String>`) using the Kafka `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer`.

Read the message as a byte array (using a `byte[]` payload type on the signature or a `Message<byte[]>`) using the Kafka `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer`.

All these deserializers have serializers counterparts.

Please have a look at the Kafka guide for more info: https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka

Read the message as a Vert.x JsonObject (using a io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject payload on the signature of a Message<io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject>) using the Vert.x `io.vertx.kafka.client.serialization.JsonObjectDeserialize`. This strategy allow to access arbitrary JSON but still permits to access the JSON content.